# Unit or Integration Testing using PHPUnit (private method dependencies)

Tags: php, unit-testing, oop, phpunit

I'm new to unit & integration testing using PHP and PHPUnit. I have one public function inside a class that have some of dependencies. all dependencies are private functions as I don't see those need to be public visibility and some says those private functions shouldn't be tested directly. so if I need to test `requestToken` function, how should I do or what is the best way to test intended tests. Thank you in advance!

```
// php v8.2

use App\Model\OauthToken;

 class A {
    
    public function requestToken(int $clientId): object|array
    {
        $token = $this->getTokenFromDB($clientId);
        if($this->checkIfTokenExpired($token)) {
            $token = $this->getNewToken($token->refreshToken);
        }
        return $token;
     }

     private function getTokenFromDB(int $clientId): object|null
     {
        return OauthToken::where("clientId", $clientId)->first();
     }

     private function checkIfTokenExpired($token): bool
     {
       // some logic to calculate if token is expired or not without dependencies. return true/false
     }

     private function getNewToken(string $refreshToken): string
     {
        // call third-party API with refresh token to get new token data
     }

}
```

Comment: If you're trying to test something that relies on a 3rd party API, you'll want to look at [test doubles and mocks](https://docs.phpunit.de/en/10.2/test-doubles.html).

Comment: Thanks! I saw them but looks like they don't work with private functions can be mocked. so I wonder these code can't be tested and are not possible for unit or integration testing

Comment: Private method are designed to be _internal to a class_. The outside world doesn't know about them and cannot use them. All you need to do is test the methods that _can be used_ outside the class. As long as they pass all the tests your class is fine. You should not make methods private if, for some reason, you want to test them as well.

Comment: in the above example, `requestToken` is the public function. so if I need to test this function, all other three private methods should be public methods as well? @KIKOSoftware

Comment: No, that's not what I am saying. I mean that if the `requestToken()` method passes all tests, you indirectly have tested all the private methods as well. You could design your tests for `requestToken()` in such a way that when `getNewToken()` doesn't work properly `requestToken()` would fail those tests. The same is true for the other private method. So by thoroughly testing the public method you test the private methods as well.

Comment: To mock the API call while keeping that function private, you might wrap the actual API call in a separate service class, and provide a method in this class for setting that object. In `getNewToken`, if it hasn't been set yet, you create the default one. But your unit test could use the other method to set a mock object there instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write tests, you don't write code to test private methods nor third-party code.

As your current design does not support *Dependency Injection* (DI), you can only start writing some functional tests. You will then notice where the pain is, and this is a learning process about writing testable code (and less a learning about how to write test code, but next to it).

This is important as another rule of thumb is: Don't refactor without tests.

Always keep the application running.

So while you learn about how to write testable code by writing functional tests that you can run automated, you also create the base to have some tests to then start with refactoring.

The refactoring then will likely aim towards dependency injection, that is favoring composition over inheritance, replacing calls to static factory methods like OauthToken::where() with gateway objects you call ->byClientId($clientId) on that you inject ready-made via the (not yet existing) constructor.

In tests you can then inject a gateway that works entirely in memory and you therefore do not need to have a database any longer to do actual unit testing.

Same applies for contacting a remote endpoint, e.g. to refresh the OAuth token, you inject another testing adapter that returns pre-made data, so that you can test with the expected behaviour of the remote API and not the remote API (that would be end-to-end tests).

---

What you experience might be induced by introducing tests *late*. *Late* means not *first*, and *first* means that you write the test-code before your write the actual code. This also stems from *Test Driven Development* (TDD), you may find some insightful resources where others write about what they did when they introduced it *late*, as naturally this is not possible to do ad-hoc when you already have some code, and then adding tests later will make you notice what is hard to test, and so it was for others.

Comment: You have made my day! I shall put some stickers around my room to keep in mind. Thanks!